# Does second countable implies countably many components?

Tags: general-topology, separable-spaces, second-countable

I was proving that a manifold has countably many connected components and this question came up. The way I did the original question is to show that components in manifolds are open and then use the fact that second countability implies separable to show that there's only countably many components. The latter argument follows from the fact that, if there's uncountably many components, then there must be some component "left out" but since that component is open, we must get a contradiction.

However, in general, components are *not* open (in fact, they are always closed). So in the general case, I do not know how to prove that separability implies having a countable number of components or if second countability would imply such (since second countability is a stronger condition). Are those implications true and if not, what are the counter-examples?

Comment: In general it does not: the Cantor set is second countable and is totally disconnected and so has $2^\omega$ components.

Comment: @bof Sorry for the confusion, I had no trouble showing components are open in manifolds or the fact that a manifold has countably many connected components. I'm mainly interested in the second part of my post, I'll edit for clarity

Comment: The product space $\{0,1\}^\mathbb R$ is not second countable but it is separable and totally disconnected so it has $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ components.

Comment: In a locally connected space the components are open. Hence a separable, locally connected space has countably many components. Of course, manifolds are locally connected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mathbb{R}$ have the usual topology and let $X$ be the set of irrational numbers with the subspace topology inherited from $\mathbb{R}$.

Since $\mathbb{R}$ is second countable, so is $X$.

But the components of $X$ are the singleton subsets of $X$, so $X$ has uncountably many components.